# Go to next iteration after finding string by looping through text file?

Tags: python, for-loop, file-io, iteration

I'm trying to iterate through a text file organized like this:

Student 1 Name
Student 1 Grade
Student 2 Name
Student 2 Grade
...
Student N Name
Student N Grade

Once I've found a students name on a line, how can I change his grade? Here's the code I've come up with, but I can't figure out how to change the line following the students name.

```
gradebook = open('gradebook.txt', 'r')  
studentName = input("What is the students name?")
for line in gradebook:
    if line.rstrip() == studentName:
        #I want to insert code here that would change the text on the line 
        #after the line where studentName is found.
    else:
        print("The student was not found.")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 temp = []
 with open('data', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if "Student 2" in line:
            try:
                # get Student 2 grade
                line = next(f)
                temp.append(changed_line)  
            # just in case Student name was the last line of the file
            except StopIteration:
                break
        else:
             temp.append(line)

   # save you changes back to the file
   with open('data', 'w') as f:
       for line in temp:
         f.write(line)
```

Comment: But I believe he wants to change the line after the detected student's name.

Comment: @digitaLink if  clause will be true only if student name found, operand in does the checking ....

Comment: But the line changed in your script will be the line with the students name. He wants to change the student's grade on the following line.

Comment: @digitaLink you are right! I have updated my answer, thanks to your remarks.

Comment: @digitaLink Thank you so much! I can now successfully isolate that line. But now I'm not sure how to change it. next(gradebook) = newValue doesn't seem to change anything. How can I fix this?

Comment: @LetzerWille, I accidentally tagged digitaLink in my last comment!

Comment: @Ian i see. So you want to save the changes back to the file? Then you need first to get all lines saved into a list, and then reopen the file and write the lines back.

Comment: Do you want to change values in the file? If so, you should open it in write mode.

Comment: @LetzerWille Haha, i had to solve a similar problem today - find a line in a file and process the next line. Did it very ugly in a `while` with a couple of additional variables and wanted to ask later on SO for a more beautiful solution. And here it is! Thanks for `next()` :D

Comment: Using `in` instead of `==` is definitely not better but worse because checking if one students name is _part_ of another students name is an entirely different operation than checking for an exact match and you may end up changing the wrong grades if there are indeed students which have names contained in other names.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to set a flag to true in the if statement, then check for the flag on the next iteration. After changing the grade, set the flag back to false.

You will also need to append each line to a variable to write them back to a new file when you are done.